How to increase file I/O and seek operations speed in VB.NET?
I need to read some bytes at known file offset in very big files (gigabytes). Now I am using this:
Using fsSrc As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, MAX_BUFFER) 
    For i = 0 To k.startas.Count - 1
        currentpos = fsSrc.Seek(k.startas(i), SeekOrigin.Begin)
        currentpos = fsSrc.Read(buferis, 0, 32)
        k.ilgis(i) = buferis(8) + buferis(9) * 256 + &H16
    Next
End Using

This portion is very slow, constant MAX_BUFFER is quite big, but this this is slow operation. Even finding and indexing of the file is faster- there I read megabyte chunks of file and search inside for indexes. But opening file and seeking to position is very slow. It is not random read- I sort "k" database that all reading points are in a row and no need to "rewind" the file position.
There is another part in program working in the same manner- reading chunks of data with random length from known positions and writing to the other file. And it is very slow too. The algorithm is tha same- seek, read, write.
For those who wondering: 6.2Gb file - reading file in big chunks and indexing every byte for 7 byte sequence is 15s. Found 5890 entries. Meanwhile reading same file (must be part in cache) and getting 32 bytes from each entry is 115s.
There are several types of indexes, up to hundreds of thousands of entries. And the slowest part is seek-read-(and write).

This is stats for 6Gb file indexing (there are several index and only one seek and read). But the main CPU load is "seek". For indexing, it is possible to make multiple threads to speed up. But how about "seek" and "read byte"?
Problem solved! Thanks to comments- MAX_BUFFER must be very small here.

is very slow: How slow is it? Is it faster than you retrieving the information from a file cabinet? What if while searching in the file cabinet you remember that the information is in a different file cabinet? No one has any idea what you consider to be slow. In computer programming, one works with measurable/quantifiable values, not your perception of what is slow or fast.


If you read several sections of the same file, you could try reading the sections by seeking to each one in sequence instead of reading them individually by starting from the beginning of the file. 2) What is "quite big"? 3) What storage is the file on? Is it a local hard disk drive, a server on the local network, or something else?


15s vs 115s. More info added in main. The speed is not very related to media!

Have you tried a smaller buffer size, maybe 32768 bytes, for the "read some bytes at known file offset" code?

You could use a MemoryMappedFile and some multithreading depending on what kind of processing you need to do.

Thank You, Andrew Morton! Small buffer solved the problem. For indexing the file, buffer must be larger, for reading some random bytes- tiny. My tests show, that 512 is optimal :). Looks like "seek" in not very good with big disk buffer. New read speed is less than second.

For CoolCoder123 - multiple threads are good for indexing (searching). But for reading data it may be bad. There is only one I/O for all the threads.

You need to tune the buffer size to the task at hand.
I usually start at 32768 bytes* and see if increasing or decreasing that improves the performance.
At a guess, using larger buffers could slow performance if the buffer memory needs to be zeroed for each call but the buffer isn't actually used/needed.

* Because I think I once read somewhere that the buffer size that's used in Windows in 16384 bytes and I often find 32768 helps a little. Even if that's out of date or inaccurate, it seems to be a good starting point.

Looking at this inside the loop:
currentpos = fsSrc.Seek(k.startas(i), SeekOrigin.Begin)
currentpos = fsSrc.Read(buferis, 0, 32)

I'm worried you have a Shlemiel the Painter situation, where each iteration starts seeking from the beginning, and the further you get into the file the more seeking you need to do.
Ideally, there will be no need to seek here at all, since you left off with the stream at the end of the prior read, or at very least be able to seek forward just the difference in bytes between the new position and where you left off after the read from the prior iteration.

SeekOrigin "begin" and "current" is benchmarked somewhere in the internet. SeekOrigin.Begin is a bit faster. The problem was in "New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, MAX_BUFFER)". The MAX_BUFFER is not the smart "cache", but is just order to read chunk of data to buffer. And every SEEK forced re-read whole buffer.
